# unity firebase ios bug

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I use only firebase message.I build for android still work fine but when build for ios. I got this error:

Unable to configure Firebase services: Google Analytics for Firebase version (50200000) does not match with Google App Measurement (50300000) version.

Initialization Exception: Firebase app creation failed

I already follow setup in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client

Anyone have ideal pls comment. Thanks you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Update]**

I finally found where goes wrong.

First, [FirebaseAnalytics 5.2.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/ce50a307b88f42a245ff59509370775f4342f3ac/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/5.2.0/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json) pod depends to `"GoogleAppMeasurement": "~> 5.2"`, and Google has released [GoogleAppMeasurement 5.3.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/5.3.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json) around end of Oct. 2018.

That means if your pod repo is targeted to the [podspec repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/) commit version including the new version of `GoogleAppMeasurement` pod, it will get the new one and cause the version number unmatched error.

The root cause is that `"GoogleAppMeasurement": "~> 5.2"` specified in `FirebaseAnalytics` podspec allows it to get the newest pod up to version 6.0 (not include), but **they are not compatible**.

**The REAL Quick Solution (or Workaround):**

Just roll back the podspec repo target to the commit version before `GoogleAppMeasurement 5.3.0` has added.

1. Use terminal and `cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master`
2. Roll back to previous commit version `git checkout 306207013c4b` (it can be any version older but not including 9cfdbf6)

Then, you don't have to manually modify Podfile each time after Unity new build :)

---

I were facing the same error just now, and I got a hint from an issue tracking on github:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1633

**Quick Solution: [Deprecated, please read above update first]**

Specify *GoogleAppMeasurement* pod version to 5.2.0 manually.

1. Just add `pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '~> 5.2.0'` this line of code to `<Xcode Project Root>/Podfile` file.
2. Run command `pod update` under Xcode project root path.

<s>However, I'm still figuring out what the reason it won't automatically choose the right version of pod. Hope somebody could answer that.</s> Finally figure out by myself. Please read the update above.

<s>**Note:-** I have tried this, but this doesn't resolve issue... Podfile.lock already contains 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '= 5.3.0', that is newer version.</s>
Seems that who note this line had run wrong command. Just delete the line to avoid misleading.

Comment: Did you run `pod update` on the same xcode project root? It should print out some logs like these:
```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
...
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement 5.2.0 (was 5.3.0 and source changed to `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` from `https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git`)
...
```

Comment: Or just delete the `Podfile.lock`, and run `pod install` again.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same error today while checking the dependencies of Application i.e
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()

My log for iOS device is:

> Unable to configure Firebase services: Google Analytics for Firebase
>   version (50200000) does not match with Google App Measurement
>   (50300000) version. Please update. Unable to configure Firebase
>   services: Google Analytics for Firebase version (50200000) does not
>   match with Google App Measurement (50300000) version. Please update.
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateInternal()
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateAndTrack(CreateDelegate, FirebaseApp)
>   FirebaseManager:m__5(Task`1)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass22_0:<ContinueWith>b__0(Task)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass20_1`1:b__2()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c:<.cctor>b__32_1(Action)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:RunContinuations()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult(T)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1:<Unwrap>b__1(Task`1)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass22_0:b__0(Task)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass20_1`1:<ContinueWith>b__2()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c:<.cctor>b__32_1(Action)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ContinueWith(Func`2, CancellationToken)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass22_0:b__0(Task)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass20_1`1:<ContinueWith>b__2()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c:<.cctor>b__32_1(Action)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:RunContinuations()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult(T)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass20_1`1:b__2()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c:<.cctor>b__32_1(Action)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:RunContinuations()
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult(T)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1:SetResult(T)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1:b__0()

If you or anyone have idea about it... comment...

Answer (score 0):

Ok... According to @findlimit updating pod worked for me. I was trying to run command `pod install` that doesn't work... Hope anyone else will get help from it...